# NGRX Effects and Angular Fire

Tags: angular, rxjs, firebase-authentication, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Wondering if someone can help me understand what is going on here.

I am running an ngrx effect that calls an auth service, the call to the service is working correctly and if it fails it also goes to the catch error correctly.

The problem is if it is successful i want to pass the original action onto the next operator (not the response from the call to auth service).

However when i do this i always get an undefined.

```
  login$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActions.login),
        switchMap(action => {
          return this.auth.login(action.user.email, action.password);
        }),
        map(action => {  **// This is undefined, but what i want is the action object** 
          console.log(action);
          this.store.dispatch(
            loginSuccessful({
              user: action,
            })
          );
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('Received error from AngularFire:', err);
          return of(err);
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out i can replace the switchMap and map with tap.

```
login$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(AuthActions.login),
        tap(action => {
          return this.auth.login(action.user.email, action.password);
        }),
        tap(action => {   
          console.log(action);
          this.store.dispatch(
            loginSuccessful({
              user: action,
            })
          );
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('Received error from AngularFire:', err);
          return of(err);
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```